# How to evaluate triple extraction in NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, text-classification, stanford-nlp

I am current NLP work, I am extracting triples using triple extraction function in Stanford NLP and Spacy libraries. I am looking for a good method to evaluate how good the extraction has been? Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard evaluation method works for this kind of task: measure precision, recall and F1-score on a manually annotated sample.

In general one can find which evaluation measure is standard for a particular task in the literature. For example [this paper](https://aclanthology.org/W12-3004.pdf) seems to address the topic (I didn't read it).